# Is it safe to rely ?__a=1 for instagram feed?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is it safe to use `__a=1` parameter to retrieve the Instagram feed of a user in JSON format ?

Can't find official documentation about that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No, not safe.

I have built a statistics bot using that method. If you hit certain rate limit, Instagram might require solving a ReCaptcha or verification via code sent to email/phone.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I can use that parameter from a logged browser, it will work fine.

Unfortunately, I cannot use it as a web-service call from a single HTTP call.